# 80s film about a ghost hotel

Tags: story-identification, movie

Back in the 80s I watched a film whose name I've forgotten.

The story was about this:

- There was an old castle that has been repurposed by the last surviving inheritor into a hotel.
- The attracting point for the tourists was that there are ghosts (which was not the case).
- A married couple (unhappy marriage) was one of the few guests there and the owner was almost at bankruptcy.
- Then the owner's ancestors decided to help out and haunt the place for real which brought way more customers.
- The husband of the married couple tried to interfere in one haunt where there was a married couple in one of the bedrooms where the male ghost knifed down the female one as he thought she had betrayed him and then killed himself.
- The female ghost fell in love with the guy for that.
- Later on there was a unscrupulous woman who tried to get the castle for herself.
- In the end the unscrupulous woman died and got together with the ghost husband while the unhappy marriage husband came together with the female ghost who managed to get a body herself again.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think that is the comedy *High Spirits*, a 1988 movie starring Peter O'Toole, Daryl Hannah, and Steve Guttenberg.  Below is a description of the movie from [imdb](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0095304/).

> When a hotelier attempts to fill the chronic vacancies at his castle by launching an advertising campaign that falsely portrays the property as haunted, two actual ghosts show up and end up falling for two guests.

Comment: That was it tnx!