# Identify a movie from the '80s: castle, trap-door, portal

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a movie that I saw as a kid in the '80s. I think the movie is also from this era. A bunch of people visited an abandoned, medieval, ruined castle. I remember that there were trapdoors in the floor, and if someone stepped on one, he fell in it and came back somewhere else through the wall. It was like a portal. Maybe there were some ghosts too. I guess it was funny too; that's why I still remember it. Please help me find this movie. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something from Abbott and Costello.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect this may be the fantasy comedy *High Spirits*, from 1988.  It features a group of tourists visiting a dilapidated Irish castle, which turns out to be haunted by two ghosts.

[image: Theatrical poster]

The plot summary, per Wikipedia:

> Peter O'Toole is Peter Plunkett, the owner of a dilapidated Irish castle which has been converted to a bed and breakfast supplying the only employment for the local villagers. Owing money to an Irish-American businessman by the name of Brogan, Plunkett has the idea to turn the castle into "the most haunted castle in Europe" for the tourist trade, inspired by his mother's stories of the castle's history of ghosts. He and his wacky staff of Irish characters set about creating ghost costumes and effects for their first group of American lodgers.
>
> At first annoyed by the inept hauntings, the American guests (including Steve Guttenberg, Beverly D'Angelo, Connie Booth, Peter Gallagher and Jennifer Tilly) soon get what they paid for as the genuine ghosts of Castle Plunkett take umbrage with being cheaply exploited and stage a full-scale paranormal event.

The entire film is available on YouTube.

The film has previously been asked about here:  [80s film about a ghost hotel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/190769/80s-film-about-a-ghost-hotel/190771) and (presumably) here:  [Movie Identification - 80s Ghost Romance Involving A Medieval Castle?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220438/movie-identification-80s-ghost-romance-involving-a-medieval-castle/222241)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just finished the movie and there were no trapdoors, so it's not that movie. So I'm still looking for it.